# How to make exception of SQLite insert function

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using SQLite to save contacts, I'm retrieving contacts from a server.

I make an SQLite database with a unique value for each contact (Phone number) as you can see here :

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATETABLE = "CREATE TABLE contacts ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "name TEXT, "+
                "profil TEXT, "+
                "phone TEXT UNIQUE ,"+
                "show TEXT )";

        db.execSQL(CREATETABLE);
    }
```

and then I made a function to be able to insert a new contact :

```
public void addcontact(contacts contact){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", contact.getName());


values.put("phone", contact.getNumero());
    values.put("profil", contact.getProfil());
    values.put("show", contact.getShow());
    try {
        db.insert("contacts", // table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values); 
    } catch (Exception e){

    }

    db.close();
}
```

But when I'm trying to insert contact already inserted with the same phone number I get an error in the log :

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (2067) abort at 15 in [INSERT INTO contacts(phone,name,show,profil) VALUES (?,?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: contacts.phone
```

How Can I handle that error and show a log message for example that the contact exists already ?

Comment: start by doing something of your exception. your catch block is empty

Comment: Please read this page: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Answer (score 1):

first, as njzk2 said , never leave a catch block empty

make a method that will search for a mobile number in the database; return true if the number exists false otherwise, and then:

```
public void addcontact(contacts contact){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", contact.getName());


    values.put("phone", contact.getNumero());
    values.put("profil", contact.getProfil());
    values.put("show", contact.getShow());
    try {


       if(checkPhoneNumber(contact.getNumero())==false){
        db.insert("contacts", // table
            null, //nullColumnHack
            values);


        }else{

         // your error message here

        }

    } catch (Exception e){

  }

  db.close();
}
```

the method name is : checkPhoneNumber

example :

```
public boolean checkPhoneNumber(String num) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE phone = '" + num+"'";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        return true

    return false;
}
```